# Apple Mach-O linker error in Xcode test

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, linker-errors

I have to include the unit test in my project. If I exclude the ApplicatioTest from target dependencies(in build phases), the application works fine. But if I include the ApplicationTest, and then build the application for run, it gives "Apple Mach-O linker error" at times(but not every time) and then after some tries, without any changes, the application builds again. 
The number of errors are 25 at some time and 1 at some other times.
Please advise me.

Regards

Comment: Please post the error message, it's impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: As i already mentioned, the error is "Apple Mach-O linker(id) error" with the message "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". It also gives a message of missing a file: "file not found: /Users/MySystem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dizmxroixhxwovcjqhauqrrmaewg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp"  Kindly help me.

Comment: Found a similar problem with Cocoapods. Using googleMaps SDK 2.2.0, the main App target builds fine, but the Unit Test target gives that linker warning. The test target was defined within the app target in the pod file as follows: target 'AppTests' do inherit! :search_paths end